# Windows Azure: need to know the data processing time

Tags: windows, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have stored some files in the form of blobs on azure and I have written an application that would access these blobs. When I host this application as a web role on azure, it works perfectly and I am happy with that. But now, I wanted to know

> “what is the query time taken to
>   access each blob file?”

I was searching for this through the Microsoft Azure Storage SLA and I found that for GetBlob request type, the maximum processing time should be within the product of 2 seconds multiplied by the number of MBs transferred in processing the request.

I am still unclear.

> What is the actual processing time of
>   my data query? How can I measure it?

Can I be able to speed up the processing time? I can understand that the processing time depends on internet speed, location of the data center where my data is being stored, and location of data center where my application is being hosted. But still, will I be able to speed up my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the SLA lists the maximum (worst case)... the actual performance you see is likely to be better.

Their are a number of ways to tune the performance of your storage access.  The most important thing is to colocate your compute and your storage.  That means you should put them in the same affinity group when you create your application and storage account.

If you ask this question over on the [Windows Azure MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsazure/threads), you might get more detailed responses.